# How to get a list of rows and perform searches for each PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 3 tables (Customers, Beehives, Inspections)
each inspection can have only one beehive and one customer. one customer can have many beehives and one beehive can have many inspections)

Ideally what i want to do is look at the most recent inspection for each hive for each customer and count how many hives are dead and how many are alive (based on the value of the 'beehive strength' field in the inspections table.

This has been confusing me for a while now and i think its because my code is hideous and most likely not the best way to do it.

I would like to know if anyone out there can help me achieve the following table:

Customer name | Most recent Inspection | Total Live Hives | Total Dead Hives

Here is my semi working code (be warned - it is ugly as all sin):

```
    $ContactsQ = mysql_query("
SELECT 
*
FROM 
Contacts
WHERE 
`Contacts`.`Status` = 'Active'
AND 
`Contacts`.`Type` = 'Rental'
GROUP BY
ContactID
");
if (!$ContactsQ) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 
echo "<table class=\"tablesorter\" >";
echo "<thead><tr>";
echo "<th>ID &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th>";
echo "<th> Name</font></th>";
echo "<th>Live Hives</font></th>";
echo "<th>Dead Hives</font></th>";
echo "<th>Last Inspected</font></th>";
echo "<th>AG</font></th>";
echo "</tr></thead>";   







// For Each Customer//
while(($CQ =  mysql_fetch_assoc($ContactsQ))) {
$live = 0;
$dead = 0;                  
$CID = $CQ['ContactID'];
                    $Query = mysql_query("
                    SELECT 
                    MAX(`InspectionsNZ`.`InsID`) Ins,
                    Hives.* ,
                    Contacts.*
                    FROM
                    `InspectionsNZ`
                    LEFT JOIN `Contacts` ON `Contacts`.`ContactID` = `InspectionsNZ`.`CustomerID`
                    LEFT JOIN `Hives` ON `Hives`.`ID` = `InspectionsNZ`.`HiveID`
                    WHERE
                    `Hives`.`Status` = 'Active'
                    AND Contacts.ContactID = $CID
                    GROUP BY 
                    `ID`
                    ");
                    if (!$Query) {
                                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                            } 





                    // For Each Hive the customer has that is active
                    while(($row1 =  mysql_fetch_assoc($Query))) {
                                                                $HID = $row1['ID'];
                                                                $lastinsID = $row1['Ins'];
                                                                $Query1 = mysql_query("
                                                                SELECT 
                                                                HiveStrength, Date, InsID, CustomerID
                                                                FROM 
                                                                InspectionsNZ
                                                                WHERE 
                                                                `InsID` = $lastinsID
                                                                ORDER BY 
                                                                `InsID`
                                                                ");
                                                                if (!$Query1) {
                                                                    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                                                                } 






                                                                // Add to total if Alive or Dead
                                                                while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($Query1))) {


                                                                                            //Get current CustomerID//
                                                                                            $nquery = mysql_query("
                                                                                            SELECT 
                                                                                            MAX(`InspectionsNZ`.`InsID`) , 
                                                                                            `CustomerID` 
                                                                                            from 
                                                                                            `InspectionsNZ` 
                                                                                            WHERE 
                                                                                            `HiveID` = $HID
                                                                                            ");
                                                                                            if (!$nquery) {
                                                                                            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            while(($nrow =  mysql_fetch_assoc($nquery))) {
                                                                                                $NCID = $nrow['CustomerID'];
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            //END Get current CustomerID//


                                                                    if ($CID == $NCID){
                                                                    if($row['HiveStrength'] > 0) {
                                                                        $live++;
                                                                    }
                                                                    elseif($row['HiveStrength'] == 0) {
                                                                        $dead++;

                                                                    }
                                                                    }
                                                                    echo $HID." - ".$NCID." - ".$row['CustomerID']." - ".$CID." - ".$lastinsID." - ".$row['Date']."<br/>";

                                                                }


                    }
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><h3>" .$CQ['ContactID']. "</h3></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='CustomerTop.php?cid=" .$CQ['ContactID']. "'>" .$CQ['Name']. "</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><h3>" .$live. "</h3></td>";
                    echo "<td><h3>" .$dead. "</h3></td>";
                    echo "<td><h3>" .$CQ['Date']. "</h3></td>";
                    echo "<td><h3>" .$CQ['RunGroup']. "</h3></td>";

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table><br />";
```

What i am getting is a list of customers but an incorrect calculation of the live and dead hives...

Please help :)

Julian

Comment: What you've posted is great because we can see that you've made an effort but in order to help, we're really going to need to see 1. an sqlfiddle (and/or DDLs for same) AND 2. the desired result set. (You appear to have 3 queries where only one is required)

Comment: The way i was attempting to achieve this was by
1) query to get a list of all customers who are active
2) for each customer - get the latest inspection for each hive they have
3) for each of those inspections, either add to the $alive or $dead variables
4) print the results to a table of customer names with values for $alive and $dead.

Im sorry, i will look into doing a sqlfiddle tonight, please let me know if you need me to clarify, as it is a confusing query written in a confising way but it is the best i could do with my limited knowledge of SQL and PHP.